# Error Code 1215 : Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, sql

I tried to create a foreign key but it show an error

> "Error Code 1215 : Cannot add foreign key constraint "

and i try to fix it but it doesn't work.

This is my script:

```
drop database if exists `manage_Student`;

create database if not exists `manage_Student` default character set utf8;

use `manage_Student`;

drop table if exists `students`;

create table if not exists `students` (
    `id` smallint(8) not null,
    `name` varchar(50) not null,
    `id_pos` smallint (10) not null,
    `address` varchar(50),
    `gender` varchar(7) check (gender in ('male', 'female')),
    primary key (`id`),
    constraint fk_stupos foreign key (`id_pos`) references `position`      (`id_pos`)

) engine = InnoDB default char set = utf8;

drop table if exists `position`;

create table if not exists `position` (
    `id_pos` smallint (10) not null,
    `position` varchar (50),
    primary key (`id_pos`)
) engine = InnoDB default char set = utf8;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create the `position` table first.  It needs to exist before you can use it for a `foreign key` constraint.

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bdf93a) is a SQL Fiddle.

Also of note:  you have a check constraint for `gender`.  MySQL accepts the syntax for the `check` constraint.  But, it does not actually do anything.  This is for increased compatibility with other databases.

If you really want to check the values, you either need to use a reference table for gender (and another foreign key constraint) or an `enum` type.

Comment: check gender like this :
     alter table `position` add constraint ck_gender check ( `gender` in ('M', 'F' , 'U') );